# Deployment Project - custom action update

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, deployment, setup-deployment

**Situation:**

I have a Deployment Project in visual studio 2010 setup to install a console application.
This console application has some custom actions written into it for the Deployment project.

EDIT:
To clarify, these custom actions are using the `System.Configuration.Install.Installer` class in .NET.
I use the `Committed`, `BeforeUninstall`, `AfterUninstall` events on this class, and mainly use them to cleanup left over files.

**Question:**

If I swap out the console application's executable with a newer version (with updated custom actions) - Will the MSI used to originally install it have any problem with the new EXE and updated custom actions on uninstall?

Comment: what are the 'custom actions' you are talking about here? Placing a shortcut somewhere?

Comment: When I say custom actions, creating a class using the .NET Installer class and binding to the Committed / Before Install / After Uninstall events.
The actions inside these custom actions range from starting/stoping the console application to cleaning up text/xml files.

Comment: As long as your new console app is updated in your install project, and you are releasing the new version of the installation, it should work just fine

Comment: So if I install the project using the MSI, into the program files directory, and copy the console.exe file overtop of the originally installed console.exe (in the program files directory) - it will use the new one on uninstall? and not some cached version of the original?

Comment: @S.Krishna I did some testing and you are indeed correct - feel free to add your comment as an answer and Ill mark it as such :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--Adding comment as Answer as requested--

As long as your new console app is updated in your install project, and you are releasing the new version of the installation, it should work just fine. Once installed, you can over-write the installation with the new executable and they should work just fine

Comment: Just a note of discovery as well, if the custom actions are removed from the console application, and an uninstallation is started - it will fail.
The custom actions need to remain in the console application for the uninstallation to work. Cheers @S.Krishna